# Browser wants the user to re-submit / refresh 1st page when pressing the back button on 2nd page

Tags: javascript, php, html, form-submit

The 1st page is a search form that resubmits to itself and displays a list of homes.   Then the user clicks on a home to display.  When they are done looking at the home, they press the "back" button of the browser and then it is asking the user to refresh the page manually.  I just want it to redisplay the last page as it was and not refresh it.

This is the way it used to work, but I cant figure out what caused it to start asking the user to refresh the page.

I'm not sure what code to show here.  I'm using a Form with mostly PHP and very little JavaScript.

What could cause Page 1 to re-submit or refresh??

Update: I figured out that it has something to do with the PHP Session, however I dont know why its working correctly now:

This is the PHP code I had at the beginning of page:

```
`<?php  session_start();
$PrevNext = $_SESSION['PrevNextH'];
$queryH = $_SESSION['queryH'];
?>`
```

This is what I changed it to and it works fine now:

```
`       <?php   session_start();
        $PrevNext = $_SESSION['PrevNextH'];
        $queryH = $_SESSION['queryH'];
        ?>`
```

All I did was indent each line twice and the problem was solved.  This does not make sense to me.  Anyone know why this could happen?

Comment: You are reprocessing the form so the form data needs to be resubmitted.

Comment: If you left page 1 to go to page 2 sending form data via POST or GET, trying to return to page 1 will cause the browser to think you want to do the POST or GET again, since it's the last HTTP request you made (and the browser understands you want to get back to that request)

Comment: Makes sense, sorry if I'm not explaining this well, however I've been doing it just this way for 2 years and its been working fine.  I still have an older website working this way.   I've made a bunch of changes in this new version and I just can point myself to the right place to what I broke.

Comment: Alan, I'm leaving the 1st page with a link like: http://example.com/homedetails/22-Fall-Creek-Trail-Branson-MO-65616/60026070/20150516224017488029000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are a few quirky issues with PHP.  The reason that this problem started was that I went into the page and cleaned up some of the code. I removed the indention's in front of my PHP code before the "DOCTYPE HTML" tag.

Like:

```
`<?php session_start();
$PrevNext = $_SESSION['PrevNextH'];
$queryH = $_SESSION['queryH'];
?>
<!doctype html>`
```

The fix was either put the indention's back in there or from what I found on a few other post here, the best solution is to put the "DOCTYPE HTML" tag before the PHP which worked also:

```
`<!doctype html>
<?php session_start();
$PrevNext = $_SESSION['PrevNextH'];
$queryH = $_SESSION['queryH'];
?>`
```